# Why show error unexpected namespace prefix xmlns in android?

Tags: android, xml

I want to display Google ads in my app but it shows error `unexpected namespace prefix xmlns` at this tag `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`. If I remove this line then it shows `Error parsing XML:unbound prefix`. Please help me to identify that where things go wrong. Here is my code.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background_port"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center"
              >

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="a151b801b7c1d6b"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    --------------------
    ---- More views ----
    --------------------

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sometimes the lint in AS is actually correct. My problem was that I tried to use https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM and it turned out the tags the library uses are only allowed to be placed in the root view of the xml file, not the child views. I don't have to mention that when I ignored the lint the library wasn't working properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error removed by CLEANING THE PROJECT

Project menu -> Clean -> Select Proj -> OK